# Can a US non-profit manage a for-profit fund?

Tags: united-states, non-profit

Is it possible to have a for-profit fund, taking on money from investors who expect to see returns, with fund management by a non-profit organization, where excess revenue from management fees would be slated to some charitable cause?

Are there any obvious legal, regulatory, or structural roadblocks to setting up a fund like this? (apart from incentive concerns)

Comment: Like a college endowment fund?

Comment: No, no, apologies for the lack of clarity. I'm referring to a for-profit fund, managed by a non-profit organization.